# Parse-server: Set logLevel

Tags: parse-server

In the latest version of parse-server, the default logLevel seem to be "info", which logs all cloud code functions.

How do I change this so it only logs errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

set a top level key in your parse-server options:

`logLevel: "error"`

see https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Configuring-LoggerAdapter